# Keep alive SSH connection with server in MacOs Mojave

Tags: ssh, mojave

In El Captain, to maintain active a SSH connection you should edit **~/.ssh/config** file to add your additional rules.

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

To maintain active for 1 hour you should add:

```
Host *
   ServerAliveInterval 3600
```

I cannot recreate the same situation is MacOS Mojave, it continue to close connections after some minutes. Any suggestions about this?

Comment: Curious: did this work in Sierra or High Sierra?          (I keep forgetting version numbers, hence for my own reference; https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS)